# Xamarin match_parent to left?

Tags: android, layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to make an Android app with space usage displayed at the top. I want a `TextView` saying "Usage:" on the left, another `TextView` saying "x.x/x.x GB" on the right, and a horizontal `ProgressBar` in between. I am currently stuck at the `ProgressBar` part: I want it to fill the space between the 2 `TextViews`, but not sure how.

If you can't tell, I am very new to Xamarin, but I'm pretty sure it's easy to do in Android Studio. (This is also my main complaint about Xamarin so far: programming is easier than Android Studio, but Layout design is much less intuitive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation. The both TextViews have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and the `ProgressBar` needs `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"`. This means: make the TextViews as wide as the Text is and stretch the `ProgressView` in between.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Usage:" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x.x/x.x GB" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Oh... I had no idea what weight does. Thanks!